# Progressive Flv Video Streaming While Downloading

Tags: asp.net, youtube, video-streaming

I am doing this small personal project in asp.net in which if I enter the Youtube video URL on my website, the video is downloaded on the server and displayed on another page. The problem is that the videos are 30 40 MB each. and to display the video, it has to be downloaded completely. I want a method in which the streaming starts of the portion of the video that is downloaded right after I entered the URL. I am downloading video as FLV.  I guess ffmeg can do this but dont know how. I am downloading the video using a desktop application. Means when I enter URL, It goes into DB and my desktop application reads it.
It is only a personal project so no copy right issue. and yes I want to download it first and then display. and I know I can display the youtube video directly but still I want to do my way

Comment: Create a `download handler`. Read MSDN pages about `handlers`.

Comment: I am downloading the video using a desktop application. Means when I enter URL, It goes into DB and my desktop application reads it.